# Magento 2 : Product Attribute Group Tab not open

Tags: magento2

I have used large number of option in product attribute ( approx 2L Option in one custom attribute ). 
When I edit product and click on attribute tab then it will not open and page has stop to working because of this large data amount.

Is there any idea please share.